# How to undo RequestFactory update

Tags: gwt, undo, requestfactory

Updating object through GWT RPC can easily be undone. We need to clone previous entity state in memory and apply it upon undo.

But when we use RequestFactory there is no concrete update operation. RequestFactory sends entity modifications to the server and updates repository entities itself. We cannot intercept update process.

How should I implement undo for updates made with RequestFactory?

Comment: Are you using InstanceRequest or just Request in RF to invoke persistence?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into modifying your server-side data structures and tables. Incorporate a temporal or bitemporal model there. Don't bother trying to hold "old" states of entities in memory, or intercept them. Keep the prior states of entities intact with time fields. Undo means locating a prior version by timestamp, and making it current. You can do this across multiple entity types simultaneously as well.

- 01:00  pizza A saved
- 01:01  pizza A ingredients changed
- 01:02  pizza A ingredients changed
- 01:03  undo to 01:01

If you want to, you can periodically sweep your database and clean up old versions. The "append-only" style of temporal writes can yield performance benefits as well.

Answer (score 0):

Request factory does not update the server entity, until you fire the request. So you can simply avoid making a call to the fire(), to prevent modifications on the server. Hope this is what you meant. Can you post the code which demostrates the way you are updating the entity, and where you want to perform the undo?

Comment: "Undo" means that modifications on the server were already done. I need to intercept server update operation to save entity state for future undo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you would like to do this. For that, say you want to undo the changes of a class, say Contact, add a field of the same type, something like previous state (just make it transient if you don't want it to mess up your persistence) so that the class looks like this:

```java
class Contact {

    Integer id;
    Integer version;

    String name;
    String phoneNumber;

    //Transient
    Contact previousState;

}
```

Now in your persist call, backup the current data into the previousState and then persist the current Contact entity. In the undo call copy data from previousState to "this".

Undo doesn't make any sense on the server, such things have to be managed on the client. I haven't come across any scenario where an undo functionality is required on the server. So please cite the scenario and the code through which you wish to accomplish this.

Comment: To perform undo on the client only, you should keep all your application state on the client. Do you think it is possible in a GWT app?

Comment: It definitely is, but you wouldn't need the entire application state, some entity like a Contact entity in an AddressBook application is what you would be interested in "undo"ing right?

Comment: No. You are wrong. Consider an ordered list of contacts for example.